# C++ error 'else' without a previous 'if'

Tags: c++, if-statement, output

Im new to C++ and have been working on an assignment

Ok so this runs, but it doesn't do the calculations
when the window comes up I type in A B or C
and then the length of the words
and it just says pay=0

here is the new code:

```
#include <iostream>




using namespace std;


char authorLevel;
int numberOfWords, payTotal;
int fixedPayAmount;



int main()
{


cout << "Enter Author Level(A,B,or C):";
char authorLevel;
cin >>authorLevel;

cout << "Enter Length(in words):";
int numberOfWords;
cin >>numberOfWords;

cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl; 
int payTotal;


cout << "Fixed Pay is:$" << fixedPayAmount << endl;
int fixedPayAmount;

//Calculations for C Level Author


if (authorLevel == 'C')
{

         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.08     
              if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.08;                     
                  }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed 600
                if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount= 600;

                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.075
              if (numberOfWords >8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)     
                    {
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.075;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to <= 19000 fixed $1313
             if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords <= 19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=1313;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.07
            if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.07;
            }
}

else if (authorLevel== 'A')
    {


         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.14     
              if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.14;
                    }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed $1050
                if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount= 1050;

                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.13125
              if (numberOfWords >8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)     
                    {                                               
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.13125;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to <= 19000 fixed $2297.75
             if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords <= 19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=2297.75;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.1225
            if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.1225;
            }
    }



    else if (authorLevel== 'B')
    {

         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.1  
              if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                        payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.1;
                    }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed $750
                if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount= 750;

                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.09375
              if (numberOfWords >8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)     
                    {
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.09375;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to <= 19000 fixed $1641.25
             if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords <= 19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=1641.25;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.0875
            if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.0875;
            }
    }


            return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use proper indentation.

Comment: remove the semicolon `;` after the `if` statement

Comment: Recheck carefully your conditional blocks ,it's just a matter of brackets :-)

Comment: Better still, use a `switch` if you can

Comment: The indentation comments are not just being picky about your question.  If you learn to use the autoindenting function of your editor, and/or pay more attention to the formatting, it will help a great deal in finding problems like the one you experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the ';' at the end of (and also replace the '=' with '==')

```
if (authorLevel == 'C');
```

as at the end of

```
if (numberOfWords <=7500);
```

**Explanation**

The `;` marks the end of a statement. So here it ends the `if` immediately. The `{...}` that follows will be executed not only when the condition is true, but *always*. Because if you put a `{...}` block anywhere in your code without putting a condition in front of it, it will be executed always.

So when you write `if (condition); { statements; }`, the program will evaluate the condition expression, and after that it will always execute `{ statements }`, unconditionally. If you remove that `;` before the `{...}`, that will work as intended, and execute the `{...}` block only if the condition was true.

The `=` is the assignment operator, not for comparison. So `authorLevel = 'C'` will set the value of `authorLevel` to `C`. Inside the `if`, the outcome of the assignment is used as the condition. The outcome of an assignment is the value that was assigned, so in this case `'C'`. And since `'C'` is neither null nor 0, it will be considered as true. So mistaking the operator causes several problems at the same time, be careful with it.

Use the `==` operator for comparisons.

Comment: I fixed the ; and the ==, thank you guys. Now its saying Error expected ';' before '{' token for line 70 else (authorLevel==A) and Error expected } at end of input for line 138 after return 0; } I know its probably a problem with my { 's but I cant find it anywhere, I went over and over and over my code. I saw someone said a switch would be better? how would I turn this into a switch?

Comment: You have a `;` line 65 too, did you removed it? `if (numberOfWords > 7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000);`
The same errors appear in lines 29,34,59,90,96,122,128.

Did you correct them all?

Comment: Yea I got them all, I left the ones that are after payTotal= numberOfWords *0.13125; and the fixedPayAmount=2297.75; statements when I took those out it said error and told me to put them back. Its saying the error expected ; before { token for the                                                                                                                                    else(authorLevel== 'A')  {

Comment: Did you forget the 'if' in 'else if(authorLevel=='A'){' ?

Comment: yea that was the problem and I missed 2 ; I got the program to run but its not giving me the answers

Comment: @Pierre-Jean I think your explanation is not very accurate. I appended my suggestion at the end.

Answer (score 8):

You have a semicolon after the first `if` (at the end of the line). Remove that and you're done.

```
if (authorLevel =   'C');
```

Should be

```
if (authorLevel ==   'C')
```

As others have noted, there are other extra semicolons and errors. Be careful!

Comment: Plus a few other places

Comment: Actually it should be `if(authorLevel == 'C')`

Comment: I fixed the ; and the ==, thank you guys. Now its saying Error expected ';' before '{' token for line 70 else (authorLevel==A) and Error expected } at end of input for line 138 after return 0; } I know its probably a problem with my { 's but I cant find it anywhere, I went over and over and over my code. I saw someone said a switch would be better? how would I turn this into a switch?

Comment: Did you fix *all* of the == and ; issues? If you could post your new code, that would help.

It's usually a good idea to write and test a smaller chunk of code than this, and then expand it. If you did that here, it would be much easier to track down errors, and to know that you're on the right path.

Comment: You're printing the results of calculations before actually performing the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

It's those semicolons at the end of your "if" statements, e.g.

```
if (authorLevel =   'C');
```

That's the equivalent of:

```
if (authorLevel =   'C')
{
  ;
}
```

In other words, it means that the block after your "if" statement is not part of the "if" statement, and is not conditionally executed.

You do it repeatedly in your code, but it's that statement I've used as an example that's specifically causing the compiler error you've told us about.

Edit:  Also, "=" is the assignment operator.  You almost certainly meant to use "==", which is the equality comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon at the end of your first `if`:

```
if (authorLevel =   'C');
```

You've  produced an `if` statement which has *no code* attached to it, except for an empty statement. You then follow that by an unrelated block of code, which has an `else` trailing it.

You need to remove the semicolon.